# How to choose a tool for handling forms with Catalyst Framework?

Tags: perl, cpan, catalyst, html-formfu

I'm using the Catalyst Framework to develop a small app. I'm actually searching for a way to handling my forms in a more common way. The [Catalyst Tutorial told about tree different modules](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aManual%3a%3aTutorial%3a:09_AdvancedCRUD) and give recommendations for 2 tools, [HTML::FormFu](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aFormFu) and [HTML::FormHandler](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aFormHandler).

Honestly, I really appreciate the TIMTOWTDI pragma, but this time I don't know how to choose between both of the two. Can you give me some feedback on these tools and why you do or don't use it?

I don't specially look for performance but much more for ease of use. *This one is the most commonly used* is also a good answer to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally have used only HTML::FormHandler. What I liked about it was the fact that you can generate the form classes based on your DBIC models.

Another extra point for using it is the fact that it has a bootstrap theme renderer so that your form fields will look fancier.

Comment: Thanx! It seems useful. When you say 'generate the form classes based on your DBIC models', do you mean by using HTML::FormHandler::Generator::DBIC or another tool?